# My resized (enlarged) image has less quality, size, and it is blurry compared by same resized image with IrfanView

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, system.drawing

I'm trying to resize / enlarge a image achieving same good results as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) program. I just took this veteran and professional program as a point of reference for comparing the resulting quality that I can achieve using my "own" image resizing algorithm within .NET.

However, my resized image is blurry in comparison, and the image size differs within the canvas size, like 1px smaller, I don't know why, I mean I don't know if this difference is a fault of mine, or a fault of **IrfanView**.

Original image:

[image]

Image Resized using **IrfanView**:

[image]

Image resized using the .NET code below:

[image]

---

Maybe the differences will not be noticeable at all unless you save both images to disk, and open them with any image viewer (like **IrfanVieew**) to pass fast between both images, so you will notice something like this:

[image]

---

This is the code I'm using:

```
Public Function Resize(source As Image, size As Size,
                       preserveAspectRatio As Boolean) As Drawing.Image

    If (size.Width <= 0) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Width bigger than zero is reqired.", NameOf(size))

    ElseIf (size.Height <= 0) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Height bigger than zero is reqired.", NameOf(size))

    Else
        Dim bmp As Drawing.Bitmap

        If (preserveAspectRatio) Then
            ' https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70916/25995
            Dim scaleHeight As Single = CSng(size.Height) / CSng(source.Height)
            Dim scaleWidth As Single = CSng(size.Width) / CSng(source.Width)
            Dim smallerScale As Single = Math.Min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)

            bmp = New Bitmap(CInt(Math.Truncate(source.Width * smallerScale)), 
                             CInt(Math.Truncate(source.Height * smallerScale)), 
                             source.PixelFormat)

        Else
            bmp = New Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, source.PixelFormat)

        End If

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp), 
              attributes As New ImageAttributes()

            ' g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None
            g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy

            ' Avoid 1px semi-transparent black borders: 
            ' https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718683/1248295
            attributes.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipX)
            g.DrawImage(source, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), 0, 0, 
                        source.Width, source.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes)

        End Using

        Return bmp

    End If

End Function
```

Why I'm getting worse results than IrfanView?. Why my image is blurry and have different size drawn within the canvas size?. What I'm doing wrong and how do I fix it?.

Please note that in the code above I tested almost all possible quality combinations. And bicubic interpolation gives me a better / sharp image than highqualitybicubic, I'm not sure if this will apply always when enlarging a image.

Comment: You may find [Image Resizing - outperform GDI+](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/11143/image-resizing-outperform-gdi) an interesting read.

Comment: I totally forgot about Lanczos!! (the filter I was using in Irfanview). Thanks. but what about the 1px drawn difference inside the canvas, that could be related to using Lanczos too?.

Comment: You should: load the Image preserving ICM information, if any (it's a bool argument to specify in `Image.FromStream()`), copy the original to a `32bit bgra` image (!important), use `InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`, pixel offset now becomes not relevant, `CompositingMode.SourceCopy` depends on the surface. -- After that, apply a mild Sharpen filter (it's a 3x3 Matrix): something like: `{  0f, -1.88f,  0f, }, { -2f, 11f, -2f, }, {  0f, -1.88f,  0f, }` would do.

Comment: I forgot: the Shapen filter needs a Factor of `~.34f` and no Bias (set to `0.0f`)